# Visual Studio like property window

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am working on an application that can be configured quite heavily. As i was creating endless labels and textboxes, I rememberd an application that had a neat way to deal with this.

mRemoteNG:

[image]

Is it possible to add a config property window like this to my own application?

Comment: See [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: aha! it's a built-in feature. not sure how i missed that. Thanks.